# Error trying to extract rows with a specific column value in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, extract

Having trouble. Here's an example of my dataframe (which has 4k rows). I want to extract rows that have a certain name in the LocationID column ("D").

```
D, AWC_Code
Yukon, 2
Unimak, 3
Taku River, 4
Banana, 5
Tailgate, 6
```

However I keep getting an error when I use this script. Thoughts?

```
awc3 <- awc2[ D == "Unimak" | D == "Taku River" ]

Error in D == "Unimak" : 
comparison (1) is possible only for atomic and list types
```

Comment: `awc3 <- awc2[ awc2$D == "Unimak" | awc2$D == "Taku River", ]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `dplyr::filter`

```
library(dplyr)
awc3 <- filter(awc2, D == "Unimak" | D == "Taku River" )
```

Answer (score 3):

In base R you can use `dataframe$column` to do logical indexing:

```
awc3 <- awc2[ awc2$D == "Unimak" | awc2$D == "Taku River", ]
```

Comment: ```awc3 <-  with(awc2, awc2[D == "Unimak" | D == "Taku River",  ]```

Answer (score 1):

I believe, you got `awc3` as a data.frame with two columns.

```
library(dplyr)  
awc3 <- filter(awc2, D %in% c("Unimak", "Taku River"))
# or, this should also do the trick 
awc2[awc2$D %in% c("Unimak", "Taku River"),]
```